# Issue with Javascript Intl.NumberFormat

Tags: javascript, currency

Can someone please explain why the following code does not work unless I hard code the json? I would like to be able to swap various locale, currency values in.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

    currency = 'GBP';
    locale = 'en-GB';

    var json = `{  style: 'currency',  currency: '${currency}', minimumFractionDigits: 0,  maximumFractionDigits: 0 }`;
        console.log(json);
        cf = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, json);
        document.write(cf.format(1887732.233) + "<br>");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "unless I hardcode the json"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your "json" is an object literal, "en-GB" isn't a locale, it's a language code. The Intl object accepts an options object whose properties and names are used as values for the generated string. Are you really asking how to generate that object using variables?

Comment: By hardcode the json, I mean repeat the json with all literals for each language. I would rather use a variable in that json parameter rather than duplicating it 50 times.

Comment: Yes, I would like to avoid creating 50 different versions of that json for each language code. I would like to plug in a variable into that json

Comment: @RobG, The reason I said locale is I saw this documentation new Intl.NumberFormat([locales[, options]]) at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Comment: @jbd—yes, I don't know what gets into standards writers heads. The value is called "a BCP 47 language tag" because it represents a language, yet the authors decided to call the parameter "locale", which it is not. However, that doesn't mean we mere mortals have to perpetuate the error. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this part:

```
currency: '${currency}'
```

which is not a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but just a string.

You need this instead:

```
currency: `${currency}`
```

or just

```
currency: currency
```

or even, which Mr. [Spock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435743/spock) in the comments mentioned, with a [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

```
currency
```

```js
var currency = 'GBP',
    locale = 'en-GB';
    json = {
        style: 'currency',
        currency,
        minimumFractionDigits: 0,
        maximumFractionDigits: 0
    };

console.log(json);
cf = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, json);

console.log(cf.format(1887732.233));
```

Comment: { currency: currency }  can be written just { currency }

Answer (score 2):

Your code works just fine without json like this:

```
var config = {  style: 'currency',  currency: currency, minimumFractionDigits: 0,  maximumFractionDigits: 0 };
cf = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, config);
cf.format(123);
```